# Is it grammatical to leave out the "and" in "try and do"?

Tags: grammaticality, omissibility

The motivational example sentence for this question turns out to be a typo. Nonetheless I think it triggered valuable discussions.

---

I came across this sentence from NYT today:

> ... Mr. Xi met with President Biden for nearly three hours to **try keep** relations from deteriorating further between China and the United States ...

I'm inclined to doubt myself if my feeling goes against NYT writings, so I did a search in COCA, which yielded such results:

> I can draw attention to these folks and to **try keep** people aware of what's going on.
> You **try keep** your feelings inside the ropes but then you weigh me down.
> I'd **try keep** focused more on the issues

This usage of "try do" without "to" or "and" seems existent, though not widely used. Is it particularly colloquial? If it is, why does NYT use it?

Comment: It seems that the article has since been edited. I couldn't find the quote: https://www.nytimes.com/2022/11/14/world/asia/biden-xi-bali-g20.html

Comment: The term *relations* appears to have morphed into *relationships*, from the NYT article:  “*And after nearly three hours spent together, they promised more efforts to repair a relationship that has been at its most rancorous point in decades.*”

Comment: I think this example is unquestionably a typo, regardless of whether the usage might meaningfully be said to exist in some conversational contexts (certainly none that I've every been aware of).

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's from [this](https://www.nytimes.com/live/2022/11/14/world/russia-ukraine-war-news-g20?action=click&pgtype=Article&module=&state=default&region=footer&context=breakout_link_back_to_briefing#after-the-biden-xi-meeting-beijing-signals-optimism-over-relations-with-washington:~:text=three%20hours%20to-,try%20keep,-relations%20from%20deteriorating)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It's been edited, and the error rectified. It now reads … **try to keep** relations from deteriorating further between China and the United States…

Comment: You are correct.  The article is grammatically incorrect.  It should be "try to keep"

Comment: To at least one Brit (me), this sounds both informal and American. I think is probably by association with similar constructions with ‘go’.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question based on a typo in a daily paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this article, *[A Diachronic Study on the Complementation of the Verb Try](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://trepo.tuni.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/84759/gradu06863.pdf?sequence=1)* published in 2013, this structure is informal and is not often used in literary texts:

> These instances are so few that it is safe to say that they are not
> used in literary texts (at least not in the period between the 1960s and the 1990s)... but in speech this pattern is acceptable to a greater degree. Perhaps the unstressed ***and*** or ***to*** between the two verbs is easy to leave out altogether.

Your examples are clearly formal so either the article is not accurate or the language is speedily changing. But when I look at this Ngram I tend to believe that this form is indeed rare compared to its alternatives *try to keep*, or *try and keep*:

[image]

Among the [Google Books hits with *try keep*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22try%20keep%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2016,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en), some will show ***try*** and ***keep*** belonging to different sentences, so this instance is clearly rare.

The article I quoted in the beginning had a very interesting statement which might explain the present tendency to use ***try+bare infinitive***:

> The bare infinitive pattern, normally found after auxiliary verbs, sounds more than intriguing since it is claimed that ***try*** *is becoming more auxiliary-like*.

Will this tendency be established as the norm? The article says:

> These types of changes tend to emerge first in spoken language and only when or if they become acceptable more generally do they make their way into the written media. Time will tell whether or not this development is here to stay.

The individual Ngram for *try keep* clearly shows that it is currently skyrocketing both in AE and BE.

[image]

So we might be witnessing this structure making its way into standard English *as we speak*.

Comment: Not only are the Ngram examples rare, but most are false positives and one is an attempt at dialect. That leaves a typo or two.

Comment: And yet it is true that [newspapers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22try+keep%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK3tmB66_7AhWIZ8AKHaKgDZ44ChD8BSgDegQIAhAF&biw=1423&bih=639&dpr=1.35) use it more and more.

Comment: @BillJ Well, apparently, this is what [King Charles said to Liz Truss](https://www.inyourarea.co.uk/news/what-king-charles-said-to-liz-truss-just-days-before-her-resignation/): _“You are very kind. It was the moment I have been dreading, as I know a lot of people have. We’ll **try keep** everything going. Come, come have a seat.”_

Comment: I don't believe a word of it. Your first graph says it all.

Comment: @BillJ Try this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22try+keep%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV6qmc7a_7AhWKLsAKHVVsCJ0Q_AUoA3oECAIQBQ&biw=1423&bih=639&dpr=1.35). You will find UK newspapers using the phrase. I am not advocating for it. I am just saying it is being used, rarely it's true, but it's there. And it's interesting: especially in articles about sports.

Comment: The Metro and football! Hardly reliable sources of good English. Probably misprints or misquotes.

Comment: Oh wow, pidgin English on the BBC website. How interesting! https://www.bbc.com/pidgin/articles/cndw903119go *Di Gunners [UK football team, Arsenal] dey try keep Simons and Gapko offside sake of dia speed.*

Comment: Yes, I know... I was surprised too!

Comment: There could  also be the possibility that the NYT reporter was using a speech to text (voice recognition) software? If that's the most commonly used term.

Comment: I've seen "voice typing", too. Hard to say, since it's not the only instance. The OP has searched COCA and found other instances...

Comment: I don't trust that final *The individual Ngram for **try keep** clearly shows that it is currently skyrocketing both in AE and BE.* The NGram charts for a great many search terms have skyrocketed in recent decades, as with [this one for *"tried **to** keep"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tried+to+keep&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), so that hockey stick chart doesn't necessarily tell us anything.

Comment: ...also I see that [this NGram chart for "**want keep**"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=want+keep&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) looks almost identical to the one for "**try keep**". Is *that* an emerging usage too?

Comment: From the Uusi-Makela article (A Diachronic Study on the Complementation of the verb Try): 'Kjellmer (2000, 116) argues that there are too
many examples of this use [_try_ + bare infinitive] in the Cobuild Corpus (of some 50 million words) for it to be
regarded as a mistake' shows a less prescriptive (more enlightened?) view than some seem to have.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Common usage does not equal correct usage. If "correct grammar" must always morph to fit "common usage", then statement accuracy is doomed. (Though even I will admit this example seems a contextually trivial omission.)

Comment: "Ngram for _try keep_ clearly shows that it is currently skyrocketing" — while it is 'sky-rocketing', it's gone from zero usage to 0.000000002% frequency (i.e. to 2 in a billion)

Comment: @ProphetZarquon 'Common usage does not equal correct usage.' But common usage **drives** acceptability, correct usage (and there are accepted changes even in grammar). 'They cut themself' is now acceptable. And so is starting a sentence with say 'and'. There were people saying 'These practices are becoming common but that doesn't make them correct' say 20, 60 years ago. We have to be prepared to move with the times in such areas.

Comment: "They" has been used in reference to an indefinite singular, since the earliest days of pressed print. **That's not new;** & it's questionable whether it was *ever* "incorrect" grammar. Again, in the case of "try to do", I believe omitting the "to" is of little consequence due to clarity of context; but we cannot demand that accuracy take lower priority than commonality, in _every_ scenario. Some common usage is simply fallacious no matter how common it becomes. In this particular case though, I think we're fine.